# Globally called constructor of a class template that adds this pointer to static list causes error

Tags: c++, list, templates, static

I have a class template that keeps track of all instances of a specific instance of the class template with a list of pointers. In the constructor, I `push_back(this)` to add the created instance to the class.  If I create an instance within `main`, it works fine. But if I create a global instance, the constructor causes an error. The error is from the `list.push_back()` and it says that the insertion iterator is out of range of the container. I have recreated the bug with minimal code.

Header file

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <list>

template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    static std::list<A<T>*> l;

    A( T t ) : val( t ) { l.push_back( this ); }
    ~A() { l.remove( this ); }

    T val;

    void print() { std::cout << val;  }
};

template<typename T>
std::list<A<T>*> A<T>::l;

#endif
```

Source file

```
#include "Header.h"

A<int> temp( 0 );

void main()
{
    temp.print();

    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
}
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the constructor call order, but does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: There are some arcane rules related to static initialization order fiasco and template instantiation order that are harder to wrangle than a herd of cats. The easiest solution here is the function static scope trick. Declare the statically-scoped objects inside a function that returns a reference to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static members of template class specializations have *unordered* dynamic initialization, meaning that there is no guarantee in what order they will be initialized relative to other dynamic initialization.

If `A<int>::l` is initialized after `temp`, then initialization of `temp` will try to access `A<int>::l` before its lifetime began, causing undefined behavior.

The usual solution to this is to put the static variable in a static function and call that instead. Local static variables are initialized when execution reaches their declaration the first time, so it is always properly ordered.

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    static auto& l() {
        static std::list<A<T>*> instance;
        return instance;
    }

    A( T t ) : val( t ) { l().push_back( this ); }
    ~A() { l().remove( this ); }

    T val;

    void print() { std::cout << val;  }
};
```

Non-`const` global variables should however be avoided as much as possible in the first place. They usually make reasoning about the code more complex and have problems such as initialization order here.

I don't know what the purpose of the instance list here is, but it has similar issues and should probably be avoided if possible. Additionally it will have quite bad performance, especially if you have many instances of `A<T>` around, because `l.remove( this );` will take linear time in the number of elements in the list. Consider using `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` instead of `std::list`.

---

Additional notes:

---

The return type of `main` *must* be `int` in C++. `void` as return type is a non-standard extension of some compilers.

---

Your class is violating the [rule of 0/3/5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). You need to define copy (and move) constructor and assignment operator with correct semantics, otherwise your instance list will not contain all instances when your class is copied.

---

You also might want to save `const A<T>*` instead of `A<T>*` in the list. The latter is dangerous. If you ever declare a variable of type `const A<T>`, then the pointer you save in the list will still be non-`const`. If you then use the pointer from the list to modify the object, you will not be warned that you are trying to modify a `const` object (which causes undefined behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Using a `block scoped` static variable (`local static` variable in a function / static function) is very good approach because initialization of `class template static data members` and other `static/thread-local` variables are `indeterminately sequenced` with respect to each other and this causing problem of accessing a variable which is not yet initialized. read more about it, at [Static non-local initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables)

But this approach will not allow to use `A<T>::l`, because then, `std::list<A<T>*> l` variable is not `static member` of class `A<T>`, It means if `static member` of a class can't be avoided due to some requirements then this unordered initialization problem has to be resolved.

Now `unordered` initialization can be converted into `ordered` initialization by using `explicit template initialization`, as follows,

```
template class A<int>; //explicit template initialization

A<int> temp(1);
```

It will make sure that `std::list<A<T>*> l` get initialized before `temp` object initialization. This explicit template initialization has to be done in each translation unit where you want to create `non-local` variable of `A<T>`. Let's look at the code,

Header file is similar (no change),

Source file

```
#include "Header.h"

template class A<int>; //explicit template initialization

A<int> temp(0);

int main(int , char *[]){
    std::cout<< "temp.val = ";

    temp.print();

    std::cout<< '\n';
}
```